# Run a shell script 100 times/sec

Tags: shell, mqtt, mosquitto

**ULTIMATE GOAL: publish 100 "heartbeat" messages/second over MQTT using Mosquitto as a broker.**

To send a single heartbeat, I can easily do `mosquitto_pub -t "ems/heartbeat" -m 0`.

I am aware of the `watch` utility in Unix systems but is not fast enough for the goal. My first approach to the problem was to scale this up by using the command `while sleep 0.01; do mosquitto_pub -t "ems/heartbeat" -m 0; done`. By subscribing to the "ems/heartbeat" topic (`mosquitto_sub -t "ems/heartbeat"`) I am *fairly* sure that the messages published to the topic are way less than the 100 expected in the timeframe of 1 second. So here is my question: how can I run a shell script - the heartbeat above - 100 times a second, or even better, how can I publish 100 messages/sec over a certain MQTT topic?

The title might seem a bit misleading compared to what is my ultimate goal, but finding a way to run a shell script 100 times/sec should do the trick. If there are different ways to tackle the problem, they are of course welcome! Thanks!

**EDIT & ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:**
The receiver of these messages is just a microcontroller that needs to check that the connection with the Electronic Monitoring System (a laptop) is alive. The need for 100 messages/sec is given by the fact that the micro is providing control to highspeed actuators and when a connection loss occurs, everything needs to be in a safe state.

The basic assumption is that the 100 messages are spread over a 1-second time span and are coming from a single entity, the EMS.

By running the time command this is the output, so no way it possible to use mosquitto_pub to send 100 messages a second, as pointed out.

```sh
time mosquitto_pub -t "ems/heartbeat" -m 0

real    0m0.039s
user    0m0.006s
sys     0m0.011s
```

Comment: Have you run `time mosquitto_pub -t "ems/heartbeat" -m 0` I would guess it takes longer that 0.01 second to run...

Comment: Must there be a `0.01` time difference between different execution? Or can you just spawn 100 processes per second?

Comment: Also what are you trying to simulate here? Are you expecting to have fleet of publishers so large that even spread over an hour you will be receiving 100 heatbeats per second?

Comment: I have updated the description with a few more details, thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is don't.

Use a proper load generating tool, e.g. jmeter has MQTT support.

Otherwise use a proper MQTT client library and connect once and then just publish in a loop. That way you don't have the overhead of setting up and tearing down a new connection to the broker for each message (which is what driving mosquitto_pub this way is doing)